# Mixing noun and verb in conjunction

Tags: grammar, is-it-a-rule

> Having a watch is essential for looking good and timeliness.

Disregarding the content of the above sentence, is it grammatically correct? To me it feels improper that "looking good" uses a verb, while "timeliness" uses a noun.

I'd rather see

> Having a watch is essential for good looks and timeliness.

or

> Having a watch is essential for looking good and being on time.

If it is indeed an error, does it have a name? How would you describe it?

Comment: The rule that eliminates unnecessary prepositions in conjoined phrases is called [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20conjunction%20reduction). It requires that the structures be identical -- prepositions like _for_ should both have similar objects if the second one is to be deleted. So the first sentence has a noun phrase and a gerund, which is not close enough, but the other ones have two noun phrases and two gerunds, which is fine.

Comment: So we do not write “we are going out for a cup of tea and a while.”

Answer (score -1):

“Looking” is a gerund aka “acting noun.” The grammar is correct. Your suggestions are good, but that’s about style.